# How to get foreign language text to display correctly in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have some text that isn't being displayed correctly in a UITextView. The "é", "ç" and "ñ" etc... are all being displayed like this:

[image]

The text is coming from a server and displays fine when viewed in a web browser.

Wondering how to go about fixing this. Thanks for any help.

here's the code:

```
  // the deal id is passed from the offersvc table selected item and into the url
  // dealID is 1020414

    NSString *jsonDealString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.**********.net/v1/public/details?id=%@&yd.key=******", dealId];

    NSLog(@"jsondealstring is %@", jsonDealString);

   // NSLog(@"deal id is %@",dealId);

    // Download JSON
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonDealString]
                            encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                            error:nil];

    // Create parser for the api
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    [self setDisplayItems:[results objectForKey:@"results"]];

    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[displayItems objectAtIndex:0];

//    NSLog(@"item from details is %@", item);

    // set the labels and text views. 

    link = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
    catStr = [item objectForKey:@"cat"];
    vendorStr = [item objectForKey:@"vendor"];
    titleStr = [item objectForKey:@"main_tag"];
```

Comment: Can we see your code of how do you get the text into the UITextView?

Comment: @PeterPajchl I added the code I'm using to get the text into the text view. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the UTF-8 encoding.

**EDIT** in response of the modified question

Simply add `NSUTF8StringEncoding` like follows

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString
                        stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonDealString]
                        encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy|NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];
```

Comment: I tried the UTF-8 encoding and the characters still show up incorrectly. thanks